# (In)equality between norm and scalar product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we always have $x=\sup_{||y||=1}|\langle x,y\rangle|$ for $x\in H$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space. Now let's narrow down our focus to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the euclidean scalar product and suppose we have a symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Then we have
$$\sup_{||x||=||y||=1}\langle x,Ay \rangle =\sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||
 $$
by taking the suprema one at a time which is possible since $\langle x,Ay \rangle=\langle Ax,y\rangle$ by symmetry. Now what happens if we drop the symmetry assumption? A priori I don't think, I can use the line of argumentation here since taking the suprema in a different order will result in the supremum over either $||Ax||$ or $||A^Tx||$ which in general are not the same. If there is not, is there at least an inequality
$$ \sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||\le\sup_{||x||=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle 
$$
for general $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the inequality is not true. if $A$ is rotation by $90^{0}$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$ then  $\langle Ax, x \rangle=0$ for all $x$.